# How to get OS name of hosts conneted in a same network

Tags: android, kotlin, tcp, wifi, arp

How to detect OS name of hosts conneted to a same network using android client. Currently informations such as ip address, mac address, vendor and host name already found by reading ARP table. Now I want to detect operation system of hosts. Is there any way to detect it.